# What does independent curly brackets do in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, brackets

So I have this block of code on the book I'm studying. What does this independent `{}` actually do?

```
self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
{
    self.name = playerName;
    self.zPosition = 10;
}
```

Is this different from

```
self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"character.png"];
self.name = playerName;
self.zPosition = 10;
```

Comment: it suppose to be `self = [super init...]; if (self) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just scope, there is no difference in the 2 pieces of code you posted, but you could declare a short lived variable inside curly braces and scope it to just those few lines of code.

```
{
    int x = 5;
}
NSLog("%d", x);  //error
int x = 10;      //legal
```

The first x variable goes out of scope after the curly's end, so that variable will be cleaned up.  It's not a commonly used feature, but could be useful to scope certain variables.  You can think of it just like an if or while block with no stipulation to enter that will run once.

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces define a local scope. It can be used simply for code readability, or you can also use it to limit the scope of local variables:

```
   For example:-

    -(void)yourMethod
   {
   {
  NSString  *str=@test;
   }
   {
   NSString  *str=@testing;
   }
  }
```

So in the above you can define two same name local variable within the two  scope. This is use of independent curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

What Kevin said.  More precisely, a group of statements surrounded by `{}` can be used anywhere a single statement can be.  When you code, eg:

```
if (x == y) {
    a = b;
}
```

you are simply applying this rule to the basic structure of:

```
if (<test>) <statement>
```

substituting `{ <statement_list> }` for `<statement>`.

Likewise with `for` and `do` and so forth.